# Win10 Print Screen Set Up - Lightshot

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, print-screen

I just installed Win10 on my new laptop and whatever I do, I'm unable to get rid of Win10 Snipping Tool.
I went through several tips on Google in regards to this.

1. Disabled PrintScreen shortcut in settings.
2. Enabled option ˝Do no let Snipping Tool run˝.
3. Restarted my LapTop multiple times.
4. Re-installed Lightshot after all of this and made sure it's options are set to activate with PrtSc button.

And still, PrtSc keeps on activating Snipping Tool, instead of Lightshot.
Not sure what else am I supposed to do and it's getting frustrating.

Please help.

Comment: Change the Hot Key for Lightshot.  This will be much (much) easier than changing Windows Hot Keys.

Comment: I want this one button to work, as it worked on my old LapTop and as it works on my Work LapTop, not gonna give up on it...hahaha

Comment: Windows has changed and keeps changing. So trying to thwart Windows is not likely to work any more.

Comment: Yeah, I know. - @john

Comment: Did you resolve it in the end @MisterOggy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the shortcut itself in `Keyboard` settings:

1. Open settings.
2. Go to `Ease of Access` -> `Keyboard` or search `snipping`.
3. Disable `Use the PrtScrn button to open screen snipping`

Also make sure that it saves correctly to registry and `PrintScreenKeyForSnippingEnabled` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard` is set to `0`.

Comment: Hello Destroy666, already did this multiple times. Issue still persists.
Tried every step I found on internet, nothing worked. Never had this issue on my previous LapTop, where I had win10 as well.

Comment: That should be sufficent, I checked on a freshly installed instance of latest Win 10. Perhaps the settings aren't saved correctly to registry? Check if in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard` `PrintScreenKeyForSnippingEnabled` value is 0. If that doesn't work, does editing other `Ease of Access` settings work correctly for you?

Comment: Every time I check, setting remains the way I put it. Not sure why it fails. And of course there is no way to simple uninstall Snipping Tool.
Also, I don't known where to find or perform: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard PrintScreenKeyForSnippingEnabled

Comment: In registry as I mentioned. Use either default `regedit` app or some 3rd party one, like Registry Workshop. Find the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard` key and look for value of `PrintScreenKeyForSnippingEnabled` for that key. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-open-registry-editor-in-windows-10-deab38e6-91d6-e0aa-4b7c-8878d9e07b11

Comment: And here I am again. Tried what you suggested. Tried all 4 ways provided in the link: https://thegeekpage.com/disable-snipping-tool/

Last two steps were unavailable for me as I could not find Snippingtool.exe or Uninstall Snipping tool from my apps. This is getting frustrating. Next step is I'm taking my PC to a local IT guy to kill that bloody app...
This makes no sense at all to be honest, don't remember the last time I was this frustrated....

Comment: Even tried mapping PrintScreen key with SharpKeys as suggested on Ms Community. This did not work, as when I tried to Type Key in the software, Snipping Tool got activated over the whole screen and SharpKeys did not detect a proper key.

Comment: So what was the value of the registry when you checked? Do you have all Windows updates installed?